# General form of a machine learning algorithm

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, algorithms

This is the general function that represent any machine learning algorithm:

$Y=f(X)+\epsilon$ , where $Y$ is the dependent variable, $X$ is the independent variable and $\epsilon$ is the random error term.
I have some doubts about this formula :

1) Do the Y and X represent the input and output of a computed machine learning model ? Or are they intended to be understood as properties of the real event that we want to model ?

2) According to this equation, if i use the same input many times i can get different values of Y. Is this true ?

Thanks

Comment: Consider this. This equation is better suited to describe a model found in population. In machine learning one calculates **Y-hat** on a sample so that a distance between **Y** and **Y-hat** is minimal for a given sample.

Comment: Could you also cite the source where this "general function" comes from?

Comment: "An Introduction to Statistical Learning: With Applications in R" Cap 2.1

Comment: Why Y-hat is considered a random variable ? It doens't have the random error...

Answer (score 1):

1) in this case X and Y are properties of the real event as you call it. The output of the model is usually written $\hat{y}$, and you would get 
$$
\hat{y}=f(X) .
$$

2) This depends on the machine learning tool you use. For example with a OLS Regression, you will always get the same fitted $\hat{Y}$ for the same input and thus also the same $\epsilon$ because
$$
\epsilon=Y-\hat{Y} .
$$

If you use methods with stochastic features (for example shuffling in NN), the output can indeed be different.

Comment: For the point 2) i was referring to the "real" equation (the one with Y )

Comment: Then the answer is yes. The different values of Y would represent the variance in your data, due to for example the precision of your measuring device.